# Solving with a limit x<<d

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion

I attempted to solve equation with a limit of $x \ll d$ ($x$ much less than $d$).

The first method without limit approach yields the correct two answers.

Second method (series limit) yields two answers but only one is approximately correct.

Third method (user input limit) yields only one answer which is approximately correct.

Is there a way to solve equation with a limit that will give the two approximately correct answers?  What is wrong with the second method?

```
Remove["Global`*"];
test = Sqrt[d^2 - (x + a)^2] + x*d - d + b*(x + a) + c
aa = Solve[test == 0, x] (* direct solving without limit x<<d *)
DD2 = test /. x -> \[Epsilon]*(d)
DD3 = Normal@Series[DD2, {\[Epsilon], 0, 2}]
DD4 = DD3 /. \[Epsilon] -> x/d
bb = Solve[DD4 == 0, 
x] (* solving with a limit of x<<d by programming approach *)
cc = Solve[Sqrt[d^2 - (a)^2] + x*d - d + b*(a) + c == 0, 
x] (* solving with a limit of x<<d by user approach *)
d = 100; a = 0.1; b = 0.2; c = 0.3;
f1 = Evaluate (aa)
f2 = Evaluate (bb)
f3 = Evaluate (cc)
```

The answer is:

```
f1 = Evaluate (aa)
{{Evaluate (x -> -0.00319315)}, {Evaluate (x -> 1.9926)}}
f2 = Evaluate (bb)
{{Evaluate (x -> 20039.8)}, {Evaluate (x -> -0.00319315)}}
f3 = Evaluate (cc)
{{Evaluate (x -> -0.0031995)}}
```

Comment: Note that by default `Solve` returns ["generic solutions"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GenericAndNonGenericSolutions.html). Second solution from `aa` is actually incorrect for given numeric values of your parameters. Try giving `MaxExtraConditions -> All` or `Method -> Reduce` options to `Solve`. Experiment with using `Reduce` instead of `Solve` to see full space of solutions for all possible values of all parameters. Also what is `Evaluate (...)` supposed to do in last three lines?

Comment: To jkuczm:  The last three lines is to convert the symbolic solution to numerical solution for given input variable values {d, a, b, c} I am doing it to test each different solve approach {aa,bb,cc} to see how numerically they are different.  I have more complex equation to work on but this one is very similar.  Note that I solved the above analytically and I have an identical solution (numerically) to aa solution.  Therefore bb and cc are incorrect.  The reason I am interensting in bb and cc method is because it is probably easier to solve more complex equation.

Comment: To jkuczm:  The complex equation has lots of above equation as terms that leads to quart equation solution

Comment: After assigning values to `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` parameters they will automatically evaluate to those values, so simple `f1 = aa` will assign numeric solution rules to `f1` symbol. `Evaluate (aa)` multiplies value of `aa` with `Evaluate` symbol.

Comment: You can substitute numeric solution to original expression `test /. aa (* {0., 199.956} *)` to see that only first solution gives zero, second doesn't - thus it's incorrect for given numeric values of parameters. If you use options mentioned in my first comment *Mathematica* will return `ConditionalExpression` solutions with conditions on parameters for which each solution is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sl = Solve[test == 0, x]

(*  {{x -> (-a - a b^2 - b c + b d - a b d - c d + d^2 - 
    Sqrt[-c^2 + 2 c d + 2 a c d - 2 a d^2 - a^2 d^2 + b^2 d^2 + 
     2 b d^3 + d^4])/(
   1 + b^2 + 2 b d + d^2)}, {x -> (-a - a b^2 - b c + b d - a b d - 
    c d + d^2 + 
    Sqrt[-c^2 + 2 c d + 2 a c d - 2 a d^2 - a^2 d^2 + b^2 d^2 + 
     2 b d^3 + d^4])/(1 + b^2 + 2 b d + d^2)}}
*)
```

And then let us expand the solutions in series in terms of d around infinity:

```
    Series[sl[[1, 1, 2]], {d, \[Infinity], 1}]
Series[sl[[2, 1, 2]], {d, \[Infinity], 1}]
```

This yields the following:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Hi Alexei, Thanks for tip.  Your method works great but it does the limit after it solves the equation for x.   Thus is why I checked your answer as a good solution because you showed me the alternative method.   However, for more complex problem the Solve will not work.  It can be made to work if test problem is simplified thus when the limit comes in (the x<<d).  I used your alternative before Solve and it gives me result similar to bb which is wrong.   Any ideas?

Comment: @Aschoolar As much as I understood you, you wish to first expand, and then solve. In other words you want to find an asymptotic expansion of the solution. Am I right?

Comment: I think you are right.  As long as the solution is approximately close the analytical ones.  I think that this is what I did in bb however it destroys the second x solution and I was wondering if I could fix that.

Comment: @Aschoolar Then you need to first expand your solution in series in terms of the parameter d, substitute the expansion into the equation and solve for the coefficients of expansion. Here there are 2 difficulties. 1) There can be several such expansions and in general they are not necessarily go in terms of integer and even same powers of d. That is one may go with powers of 1/d, another with, say, 1/d^1/3 etc.

Comment: Continuation: In the case of small solution this may be fixed using the, so-called, the Newton's polygon. You will find the description here: M. M. Vainberg and V. A. Trenogin, Theory of branching of solutions of non-linear equations. (Noordhoff, Leyden, 1974). 2) There are many parameters in your equation, and their relation to d are not specified. Are they as large as d, or smaller than d, or what? The form of the solution depends on this. I do not think that any general discussion of such a matter has any sense. It is better to discuss a specific equation.

Comment: Please see the link below,  http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1106375?p_p_auth=znbHoZ70.   The toycode.nb is the equation I am working on.